# Determine width of new element in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a robust way to determine width of element tree immediately after creating with document.createElement and placing with something.appendChild ? Element's offsetWidth or getBoundingClientRect works fine in Firefox and IE but not in Google Chrome. It only works with setTimeout but not with zero timeout. 200 milliseconds usually does it. I've read somewhere that accessing offsetWidth triggers reflow but it does not in Google Chrome v47. Maybe it is related to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290399.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to use a timeout with clientWidth :

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(div);
var div_width = div.clientWidth;
div.innerHTML = div_width;
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the width of the element in a variabele using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question properly but you cannot get the Element width before attaching to the DOM.
Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test').clientWidth;
var div = document.createElement('div');

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div).innerHTML = 'new element';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andreasonny83/5ddtzaf6/

Comment: "but you cannot get the Element width before attaching to the DOM." Thanks for a good point, but I attached before reading the property.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out it was because of images and I solved it by specifying fixed dimensions. (which is unpleasant for my design)
IE and Firefox do not need it, possibly they load images before returning parent element's width.
Thanks everybody for their help.